# Saving local copy of text area entry

Tags: mysql, textarea, offline

Previously when covering events I've typed my reports into an html file and ftp'd it to the server. If I lose connectivity or the laptop crashes, I've got the last saved copy.

We just switched our event coverage area to a database holding Textile-formatted entries done via a web form text area.

Is it at all possible to create a mechanism whereby a local copy of the textarea is saved so I can keep working during connectivity failure? Using Windows on the laptop. Guess the low tech way would be to type in a word processor and just keep pasting into the web form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021106/clent-side-data-storing-dom-storage-or-html5-local-storage) features the browsers have to offer.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is a nice idea, cookies might also be a solution (which even works in older browsers) if the texts are not too long.
However, I'd use server-side backups (created automatically via AJAX requests) and only fall back to local backups if there's no connection to the server. You can never know if local backups persist when the browser or even the whole system crashes.